# How to enable all authenticated routes to show the Devise ajax Login form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I have implemented devise to accept Ajax Login and have created a form to login via ajax which I have put up in a **modal**. However, only when I set up event binders for specific buttons, which trigger the modal ( Such as "**Login now Button**", am I am able to see the form and login. However, I want the modal to appear for any restricted route. ( For example, if I click on : "**Add review**" button, the modal should appear for login( If the user is unauthenticated ). How do I achieve this ?  )

Can I add a specialized class to all the links which require authentication so that I can target them?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you need a handler for your ajax authentication in your JS.

The problem you have is that Rails does not invoke JS unless you explicitly define it. Especially with the likes of user authentication, your application will do nothing unless you tell it to:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:error", function(xhr, status, error){
   if(xhr.status === "401") {
      // invoke modal
   }
});
```

---

Devise returns a `401 - Unauthorized` error whenever you hit an action without the right credentials:

[image]

This means that if you send an Ajax request (with `remote: true` etc), you'll be able to capture this response and use it to invoke the modal.

I don't know how you're invoking your modal form; the code above will give you the ability to put your own functionality into the function.

--

We've done something [similar](http://firststopcosmeticshop.herokuapp.com) (just click "login" at the top):

[image]

We had to change the `Devise::SessionsController` a little to get it working. I can do the same if you need it; I think sending a standard request, as above, will work as reqired.

---

**Update**

Okay this is a head-burner.

I'm sure there *has* to be a way to send the request to the server & evaulate the response.

The most basic implementation of this would be to make *every* link go through ajax, although this would kill a lot of the [Rails convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)...

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // send via ajax & then monitor the response
});
```

I've been trying to find a way to fire the link, capture the response in JS and then show the modal if the response is `401` etc...

There has to be a way to do it. Let me keep checking

Comment: This is a brilliant method. I definitely did not think about this. I was thinking maybe I would have to put up a check in every link to see if the user is authenticated or not and if not, put up a class.

Comment: Let me check and then mark this answer if I am able to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks buddy - it might take some tweaking, but should work in the end

Comment: Umm.. Now that I see it, I think that this is not the correct way of doing it. If the route is unauthenticated, how will I check if the modal needs to trigger in it?

Comment: If the route is unauthenticated, Devise should return the 401. Because Ajax won't redirect, it should display the 401 error, which you can use to invoke the modal

Comment: Yes, but if I click on a link which redirects to an unauthenticated route, how would I stop the default behaviour of every link to refresh the page and go to that route, rather than loading the modal? I hope you understood me.

Comment: I was under the impression that you were going to send an ajax request for these links, or is it for *any* link?

Comment: Umm.. Any link. :P ( Thats what is making my head boggle for the answer. ) Any useful tips??

Comment: Let me think. You can do it but capturing the request will be the hard part

Comment: I would be really really grateful if you can provide a way of doing this.